# RoutingHTTPServer not found build using xcodebuild

Tags: ios, appium, bootstrapping, xcodebuild

**Mac OS:**  10.13.4

**Xcode:** 9.3

**Appium:** 1.7.2

---

I am unable to build WebDriverAgent and install WebDriverAgent using xcode. I've reinstalled Appium and the current user does have R/W permissions in the folder where the appium modules are installed. I've also followed the [real device setup tutorial](https://github.com/appium/appium-xcuitest-driver/blob/master/docs/real-device-config.md)

```
2018-04-12 10:47:58.039414-0500 WebDriverAgentRunner-Runner[233:6835] Running tests...
2018-04-12 10:47:58.924245-0500 WebDriverAgentRunner-Runner[233:6835] The bundle “WebDriverAgentRunner” couldn’t be loaded because it is damaged or missing necessary resources. Try reinstalling the bundle.
2018-04-12 10:47:58.925176-0500 WebDriverAgentRunner-Runner[233:6835] (dlopen_preflight(/var/containers/Bundle/Application/D2529C60-100A-4A31-AD0D-C5F4A33920F2/WebDriverAgentRunner-Runner.app/PlugIns/WebDriverAgentRunner.xctest/WebDriverAgentRunner): Library not loaded: @rpath/RoutingHTTPServer.framework/RoutingHTTPServer
  Referenced from: /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/D2529C60-100A-4A31-AD0D-C5F4A33920F2/WebDriverAgentRunner-Runner.app/PlugIns/WebDriverAgentRunner.xctest/Frameworks/WebDriverAgentLib.framework/WebDriverAgentLib
  Reason: no suitable image found.  Did find:
    /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/D2529C60-100A-4A31-AD0D-C5F4A33920F2/WebDriverAgentRunner-Runner.app/PlugIns/WebDriverAgentRunner.xctest/Frameworks/WebDriverAgentLib.framework/Frameworks/RoutingHTTPServer.framework/RoutingHTTPServer: required code signature missing for '/private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/D2529C60-100A-4A31-AD0D-C5F4A33920F2/WebDriverAgentRunner-Runner.app/PlugIns/WebDriverAgentRunner.xctest/Frameworks/WebDriverAgentLib.framework/Frameworks/RoutingHTTPServer.framework/RoutingHTTPServer'
)
2018-04-12 10:47:59.008 xcodebuild[68163:1492596] Error Domain=IDETestOperationsObserverErrorDomain Code=6 "Early unexpected exit, operation never finished bootstrapping - no restart will be attempted" UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=Early unexpected exit, operation never finished bootstrapping - no restart will be attempted}

Testing failed:
    Early unexpected exit, operation never finished bootstrapping - no restart will be attempted
** TEST FAILED **
```

Answer (score 0):

Follow below step:

Go to your appium installed path and go node_modules/appium-xcuitest-driver/WebDriverAgent and run below command from WebDriverAgent:

```
bashbash Scripts/bootstrap.sh -d Scripts/bootstrap.sh -d
```

and then execute below command from same folder

```
mkdir -p /Resources/WebDriverAgent.bundle
```

This will solve your problem

Comment: Hi Harveer, unfortunately the RoutingHTTPServer error still persists.

Comment: @Rlupo07 have you re-build your WDA project after installing bootstrap dependency ?

Comment: I have re-built the WDA project after installing the bootstrap dependencies. I was able to fix this issue by linking the RoutingHTTPServer.framework manually in xcode.

Comment: Hey @Rlupo07 up vote the answer if it solve your problem.

Comment: this answer did not solve the problem being experienced.

Answer (score 0):

To fix this issue link the RoutingHTTPServer.framework in xcode on the general tab in the section Linked Frameworks and Libraries. [Look here to see where to do this in xcode](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VIkdw.png)

Also if you're running on simulators you'll have to use appium's 1.8 beta